# React annotating components to call a function before rendering them

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a RBAC use case such that all the components will be annotated and before rendering them, a function(check access) will be called because of the annotation. The function(check access) will decide whether to render it or not. 
Is this possible?

I do not want to use switch or if-else for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use state to store current user role, then in render use `switch case` to decide what to render.
For [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-archimedes-1o5l5)

Not sure if this is what you want